# Reduction formula for $\int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: reduction-formula

So I am trying to find the reduction formula for $\int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$.

**My attempt:** Taking $x^m$ as the second function and integrating by parts, I got,

$I_n=\frac{(n-1)}{m+1}I_{n-2,m+1}$. But the given answer is $\frac{(n-1)!m!}{(m+n)}$. How do I go from my answer to the one given in the textbook? I tried manipulating my answer, but it isn't the same as the one in the textbook. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something is missing in the textbook's answer. Have you typed it correctly?

Comment: How did you get a factorial in your reduction formula?  Differentiating the $(1-x)^{n-1}$ factor only gives you $n-1$ not $(n-1)!$.

Comment: Please don't forget to write $dx $ and the integration limits.

Comment: I edited it. Ok! I will write dx next time! Sorry it slipped my mind!

Comment: Is it a definite or indefinite integral?

Comment: definite integral with lower limit equal to 0 and upper limit equal to 1.

Comment: Is your left-hand side $I_{n-1,m+1}$?  Note $n$ doesn't jump by 2.

Comment: Then write the limits in the body of the question. Is there the factorial sign in the denominator of the textbook answer?

Comment: No,there isn't a factorial sign in the denominator.

Comment: Then it is a misprint. Does the question ask to find the reduction formula or to evaluate the integral?

Comment: It asks to to deduce from the answer I gave, the result I am trying to prove. Thanks for taking your time and answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me take $$J_{m,n}=\displaystyle\int_0^1x^m(1-x)^n\,dx.$$ This is really your $I_{m, n+1},$ but this renaming make it symmetric and easy to work with. For example, the substitution $x=1-t$ gives us $$J_{m,n}=J_{n, m}\tag1$$ which will transform as $I_{m, n+1}=I_{n, m+1}$ in to old notation. Note that $J_{m,0}=\dfrac{1}{m+1}$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ (including zero). Letting $u=x^m$ and $dv=(1-x)^ndx$ we get $$J_{m,n}=\dfrac{m}{n+1}J_{m-1, n+1}\tag2$$ via integration by parts. Also because of $(1)$ identity, we have $$J_{m,n}=\dfrac{n}{m+1}J_{m+1, n-1}\tag3$$ for free. In fact, this is exactly what you get after integrating by parts with $u=(1-x)^n$ and $dv=x^mdx.$ Lets apply this third identity repeatedly as: $$J_{m,n}=\dfrac{n}{m+1}J_{m+1, n-1}=\dfrac{n}{m+1}\dfrac{n-1}{m+2}J_{m+2, n-2}$$ to derive $$J_{m,n}=\dfrac{n}{m+1}\dfrac{n-1}{m+2}\cdots\dfrac{1}{m+n}J_{m+n, 0}=\color{Green}{\dfrac{m!\,n!}{(m+n+1)!}}.$$ Now it is not difficult to rewrite this in your old notation.

Comment: Thank you Bumblebee! It is very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the integral in question is from $0$ to $1$. The reduction formula you obtained is correct, except for the fact that you should write $I_{n-1,m+1}$ instead of $I_{n-2,m+1}$. The answer in the textbook intends obviously to show the value of the integral (after the reduction is repeatedly done till $I_{0,m+n} $).

However there is an error in the textbook formula (if you correctly cited it). The correct one is
$$\frac{(n-1)!m!}{(m+n)\color{red}!}.
$$

Comment: Ok thanks! I have one more question though. The m! in the numerator. I did it again and my answer comes out as (n-1)!/(m+n)! I must have made a mistake. But I just wanted to ask is there m! in the numerator?

Comment: Again, thank you so much!

Comment: In the denominator you obtain: $(m+1)(m+2)\cdots (m+n) $. This is $\frac {(m+n)!}{m!} $.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: The formula is much nicer if one starts with $(1-x)^n$ instead of $(1-x)^{n-1}$. I wonder what kind of idea had the author of the problem.

Comment: Yeah. I solved that one. It was better than this one.